# Optimal randomized algorithm for set cover

Tags: algorithms, approximation, randomized-algorithms

[This cstheory.SE](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/14189/is-there-a-randomized-algorithm-for-set-cover) post gives various randomized approximation algorithms for the set cover problem. Is there a randomized algorithm (which runs in $\mathrm{poly}(n)$ time) for the set cover problem which achieves an approximation ratio of $1$ (with high probability)? Is it possible to achieve such an algorithm, or is this still unknown?

Answer (score 1):

Approximation ratio of 1 means that it outputs an exact solution (so it is not an approximation algorithm but rather an exact algorithm).  Set cover is known to be NP-hard, so there is no such polynomial-time randomized algorithm, unless RP = NP.

Comment: @Steven, good point, thank you.  I have revised my answer.